# How to mass-update Apple Wiki server directly in Postgres

Tags: osx-server, postgresql, server.app

I migrate a wiki that had a lot of broken link to a domain that no longer exist.
How can I massively update my database, instead of change any single link?

My idea is to connect in postgres and update manually the database with

```
update table set field = replace(field, 'cat', 'dog')
```

Someone think it's possible?
In which table and field I can found my entries?